# Cancellation of Asymptotics

Tags: asymptotics, function-and-relation-composition

Suppose $f,g,h$ are real functions defined on a neighborhood of $\infty$ such that $f\circ g=\Theta(f\circ h)$. Under what conditions on $f$ does it follow that $g=\Theta(h)$?

For instance, it appears that when $f$ is bilipschitz, the result follows. Does it follow for any weaker condition on $f$?

Answer (score 0):

One practical, weaker condition is $$f(x)=\Theta(x^p) \quad \text{ for some } \ p>0$$ It yields the desired conclusion in a rather direct way: $g^p=\Theta(f\circ g) = \Theta(f\circ h) = \Theta(h^p)$, hence $g=\Theta(h)$.

Generalizing, we get close to the tautology territory, but the following may still be useful. It suffices to assume that there is a constant $C$ such that 
$$ b\ge  C a \implies f(b)\ge 2 f(a) \tag{1}$$
Indeed, if $g(x)$ is a lot larger than $h(x)$, property (1), applied iteratively, implies that $f(g(x))$ is a lot larger than $f(h(x))$. Same with $g$ and $h$ reversed.